# SQL - Select next date query

Tags: sql

I have a table with many IDs and many dates associated with each ID, and even a few IDs with no date.  For each ID and date combination, I want to select the ID, date, and the next largest date also associated with that same ID, or null as next date if none exists.

Sample Table:

```
ID      Date
1       5/1/10
1       6/1/10
1       7/1/10
2       6/15/10
3       8/15/10
3       8/15/10
4       4/1/10
4       4/15/10
4
```

Desired Output:

```
ID       Date       Next_Date
1        5/1/10     6/1/10
1        6/1/10     7/1/10
1        7/1/10     
2        6/15/10    
3        8/15/10    
3        8/15/10    
4        4/1/10     4/15/10
4        4/15/10
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT
    mytable.id,
    mytable.date,
    (
        SELECT
            MIN(mytablemin.date)
        FROM mytable AS mytablemin
        WHERE mytablemin.date > mytable.date
            AND mytable.id = mytablemin.id
    ) AS NextDate
FROM mytable
```

This has been tested on SQL Server 2008 R2 (but it should work on other DBMSs) and produces the following output:

```
id          date                    NextDate
----------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-06-01 00:00:00.000
1           2010-06-01 00:00:00.000 2010-06-15 00:00:00.000
1           2010-07-01 00:00:00.000 2010-08-15 00:00:00.000
2           2010-06-15 00:00:00.000 2010-07-01 00:00:00.000
3           2010-08-15 00:00:00.000 NULL
3           2010-08-15 00:00:00.000 NULL
4           2010-04-01 00:00:00.000 2010-04-15 00:00:00.000
4           2010-04-15 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 00:00:00.000
4           NULL                    NULL
```

**Update 1:**
For those that are interested, I've compared the performance of the two variants in SQL Server 2008 R2 (one uses MIN aggregate and the other uses TOP 1 with an ORDER BY):

Without an index on the date column, the MIN version had a cost of 0.0187916 and the TOP/ORDER BY version had a cost of 0.115073 so the MIN version was "better".

With an index on the date column, they performed identically.

Note that this was testing with just these 9 records so the results could be (very) spurious...

**Update 2:**
The results hold for 10,000 uniformly distributed random records.  The TOP/ORDER BY query takes so long to run at 100,000 records I had to cancel it and give up.

Comment: it is better to use ordering than aggregative functions. It you have a big table especially

Comment: @Andrii: I can't speak for other DBs but on SQL Server it shouldn't make a difference.  If there's an index it's clever enough to know it can just read the first row; if there's no index it has to scan the whole table either way.  In fact, with an ORDER BY it might be slower since it would have to do an O(n*lg(n)) sort instead of an O(n) scan.

Comment: This is a mssql db with the query being passed through via access which means the LIMIT query wouldn't work anyways.  The min query above worked perfectly with the slight addition of adding mytable.id = mytablemin.id in the WHERE statement.  The query is a little sluggish, but there isn't an index on the date field I'm using right now.

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT 
    id, 
    date, 
    ( SELECT date 
      FROM table t1
      WHERE t1.date > t2.date 
      ORDER BY t1.date LIMIT 1 ) 
FROM table t2`

Answer (score 1):

If your db is oracle, you can use `lead() and lag()` functions.

```
SELECT id, date, 
LEAD(date, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC NULLS LAST) NEXT_DATE,
FROM Your_table
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: The above code produces an error for me - the 0 should be null as oracle sql complains about it being an incompatible data type (number instead of date) the below works fine though:               SELECT id, date, LEAD(date, 1, null) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date DESC NULLS LAST) NEXT_DATE, FROM Your_table

Answer (score 0):

I think self `JOIN` would be faster than subselect.

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT 1 AS ID, '2010-05-01' AS Date
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, '2010-06-01'
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, '2010-07-01'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, '2010-06-15'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, '2010-08-15'
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, '2010-08-15'
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, '2010-04-01'
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, '2010-04-15'
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, ''
 )
 
 SELECT
    dates.ID,
    dates.Date,
    nextDates.Date AS Next_Date
 FROM
    dates
 LEFT JOIN
    dates nextDates
    ON nextDates.ID = dates.ID
    AND nextDates.Date > dates.Date
 LEFT JOIN
    dates noLower
    ON noLower.ID = nextDates.ID
    AND noLower.Date < nextDates.Date
    AND noLower.Date > dates.Date
 WHERE
    dates.Date > 0
    AND noLower.ID IS NULL
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4sWRLt2hxjik5HqiJ21ez8/1