# SQL Join based on dates- Table2.Date=Next date after Table1.Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, join

I have two seperate tables which I want to join based on Dates. However, I don't want the dates in the tables to be equal to one another I want the date  (and accompanying value) from one table to be joined with the next date *available* after that date in the second table.

I've put an example of the problem below:

Table 1:

```
Date          Value
2015-04-13    A   
2015-04-10    B
2015-04-09    C
2015-04-08    D
```

Table 2:

```
Date          Value
2015-04-13    E    
2015-04-10    F
2015-04-09    G
2015-04-08    H
```

Desired Output Table:

```
Table1.Date   Table2.Date   Table1.Value   Table2.Value
2015-04-10    2015-04-13    B              E
2015-04-09    2015-04-10    C              F
2015-04-08    2015-04-09    D              G
```

I'm at a bit of an ends of where to even get going with this, hence the lack of my current SQL starting point!

Hopefully that is clear. I found this related question that comes close but I get lost on incorporating this into a join statment!!
[SQL - Select next date query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609671/sql-select-next-date-query)

Any help is much appreciated!

M.

EDIT- There is a consideration that is important in that the day will not always be simply 1 day later. They need to find the next day *available*, which was in the original question but Ive update my example to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the next available date, and that might not necessarily be the following date (eg. date + 1) you'll want to use a correlated subquery with either `min` or `top 1`.

This will give you the desired output:

```
;WITH src AS (
    SELECT 
       Date,
       NextDate = (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM Table2 WHERE Date > t1.Date) 
    FROM table1 t1
) 

SELECT src.Date, src.NextDate, t1.Value, t2.Value 
FROM src 
JOIN Table1 t1 ON src.Date = t1.Date
JOIN Table2 t2 ON src.NextDate = t2.Date
WHERE src.NextDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY src.Date DESC
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/128bd/1)

Comment: This correctly addresses the condition required that it is the next "available day"- Thanks jpw!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
select  [Table 1].Date,[Table 1].Value,[Table 2].date,[Table 2].Value
from    [Table 1]
join    [Table 1]
    on  dateadd(dd,1,[Table 1].date) = [Table 2].date
```

Answer (score 0):

i'd go with an outer apply:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 * 
  FROM  Table2 t2
  WHERE t2.Date > t1.Date
  ORDER BY t2.Date) t2
ORDER BY t1.Date DESC
```